# How can i fix project dependency tree problem in react?

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have installed react-spring and 'npm audit fix --force'. Then i can't start my react project. It shows me 'There might be a problem with the project dependency tree'. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: What's your node.js version?

Comment: Try to update all your dependencies, not just the ones `audit` wants to you. `--force` is risky and is what broke it.